# Mean of grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data in a dataframe regarding salaries of employees. Each employee also has data stored about their sex, discipline, years since earning phd, and years working at the current employer. An example of the data is as follows.

```
    rank    dsc phd srv sex     salary
1   Prof    B   19  18  Male    139750
2   Prof    B   20  16  Male    173200
3   Asst    B   4   3   Male    79750
4   Prof    B   45  39  Male    115000
5   Prof    B   40  41  Male    141500
6   Assoc   B   6   6   Male    97000
7   Prof    B   30  23  Male    175000
8   Prof    B   45  45  Male    147765
9   Prof    B   21  20  Male    119250
10  Prof    B   18  18  Female  129000
```

What I want to access is the mean salary of all employees grouped by both sex and a range of ten years of service. For example; Males that have 0-10 years of service, females with 0-10 years of service, Males that have 11-20 years of service, etc. I can get the mean of a range of workers with ranges of years working without separating by the sexes by doing:

```
 serviceSalary = data.groupby(pd.cut(data['yrs.service'], np.arange(0, 70, 
 10)))['salary'].mean()
```

What further can I do to add a third grouping to this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can groupby multiple columns with a list as the first argument, so instead of just one:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(pd.cut(df['srv'], np.arange(0, 70, 10)))['salary'].mean()
Out[11]:
srv
(0, 10]      88375.0
(10, 20]    140300.0
(20, 30]    175000.0
(30, 40]    115000.0
(40, 50]    144632.5
(50, 60]         NaN
Name: salary, dtype: float64
```

can pass `'sex'` too:

```
In [12]: df.groupby([pd.cut(df['srv'], np.arange(0, 70, 10)), 'sex'])['salary'].mean()
Out[12]:
srv       sex
(0, 10]   Male       88375.000000
(10, 20]  Female    129000.000000
          Male      144066.666667
(20, 30]  Male      175000.000000
(30, 40]  Male      115000.000000
(40, 50]  Male      144632.500000
Name: salary, dtype: float64
```

Comment: To do three, do `groupby([a, b, c])` etc.